# error opening a crystal report on development machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I get error Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack when trying to programmatically display a Crystal Report developed in the Crystal Reports environment.

I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 and trying to I have posted the entire code I am using for calling this report below, as well as the stack trace. The problem is occuring in my VS development environment. I have seen several posts and solutions for this when it occurs after publishing the application. I am very new to Crystal Reports, and I am unable to find a way to make this work. The is occurring at the load point.

Thanks for any help

```
rpt properties
Build Action: Content
Cope to Output Directory: Do not copy
Custom Tool: blank
Custom Tool Name: blank



Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Public Class CrystalReportsController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    Public Function EmployeeQuoteLanscape() As ActionResult
        Dim rptH As New ReportClass()
        rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reprots/Quote/EmployeeQuoteLandscape.rpt")
        rptH.Load()
        rptH.SetDataSource("")
        Dim stream As IO.Stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
        Return File(stream, "application/pdf")
    End Function
End Class
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.

Source Error:

Line 6:          Dim rptH As New ReportClass()
Line 7:          rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Reprots/Quote/EmployeeQuoteLandscape.rpt")
Line 8:          rptH.Load()
Line 9:          rptH.SetDataSource("")
Line 10:         Dim stream As IO.Stream = rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)

Source File: D:\Visual Studio Projects\GBIP\gbip_new\gbip_new\Controllers\CrystalReportsController.vb    Line: 8

Stack Trace:

[COMException (0x80041811): Unsupported Operation. A document processed by the JRC engine cannot be opened in the C++ stack.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +138
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +546

[CrystalReportsException: Load report failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +647
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +1799
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) +278
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load() +38
   gbip_new.CrystalReportsController.EmployeeQuoteLanscape() in D:\Visual Studio Projects\GBIP\gbip_new\gbip_new\Controllers\CrystalReportsController.vb:8
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult *) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +126
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20() +68
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +184
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +45
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034

Answer (score 0):

The word "Reports" is misspelled in your filepath.  Perhaps that's the problem?